# PHP gives wrong value or none at all

Tags: php

Ok, so I'm having a strange problem: when fetching value of my DB i get some rows OK, and some not at all. I'm using the combination od javascript and PHP to get the values out.

```
function fun(){     
        <?php
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pitanja` WHERE `rBr` LIKE '$rb';",$connection);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $pi=$row['pit'];
            $odgo=$row['odg'];
            $opt1=$row['opt1'];
            $opt2=$row['opt2'];
            $opt3=$row['opt3'];
            $bod=$row['point'];
        ?>
```

this way i get the values. I have 7 inputs in my DB and the first 2 i get what i should get, then the next 2 i don't , the one after that i do, and the rest i don't. I figured that i get the values where $odgo and $opt values are int. In my DB in the rest of rows, those values are text and i can't get them out. My function won't start and nothing happens.

```
$hig=$hig+($bod*10);
mysql_query("UPDATE `gagq`.`user` SET `highscore` = '$hig' WHERE `user`.`id` ='$uid';");
```

Also, this gives the result of 6400 every time, even though `$hig` has initial value of 0 and `$bod` of 100.

Comment: Em... the 2nd line in your quoted code is a syntax error.. are you sure that is correct?

Comment: why `function fun(){ ` is outside the `<?php` tags?? is that a JS function??? if that's the case, it will never work

Comment: it is JS. But it works. Partially. What I wanna do is make a quiz that will get questions from DB. And it works until i get to the question where instead of answers that are numbers, i get answers that are text in DB. Why do you say it won't work?

Comment: How can i make quiz ? I mean, without different .php file for each question...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a while loop:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $pi=$row['pit'];
            $odgo=$row['odg'];
            $opt1=$row['opt1'];
            $opt2=$row['opt2'];
            $opt3=$row['opt3'];
            $bod=$row['point'];
}
```